# How can I set the logger level with xml transformation. I am using SlowCheetah

Tags: xml, log4net, configuration-files, slowcheetah

I want to set the logger level value to "WARN" in the release log4net.config file. the value in the debug config file is set to "DEBUG"

```
<logger name="NHibernate" additivity="false">
    <level value="WARN"/>
    <appender-ref ref="NHibernateAppender"/>
</logger>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only intend to change the attribute value, you could also do it this way using [SetAttributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(v=vs.110).aspx).

```xml
<logger name="NHibernate" xdt:Locator="Match(name)">
    <level value="WARN" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes"/>
</logger>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to do it or a least on way to do it.

```
<logger name="NHibernate" xdt:Locator="Match(name)">
   <level value="WARN" xdt:Transform="Replace"/>
</logger>
```